# ThreeJS Turn Texture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I created texture with canvas, but I have little problem. I couldn't turn my texture like in image. How can i make this ?

```
   setTexture = (name, font = 20) => {    

      const canvas = window.document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = 256;
      canvas.height = 128;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.font = `${font}pt Arial`;
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
      ctx.fillText(
          name || "unnamed",
          canvas.width / 2,
          canvas.height / 2
      );

      const texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
      texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
      texture.repeat.x = -1;
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
      return texture;
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rotate your texture, you could either update the UVs in the geometry, or you could use the [`texture.rotation`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.rotation) modifier.

```
const texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.rotation = Math.PI; // 180 deg in radians
```

If the rotation isn't pivoting around the point you'd like, you can set [`texture.center`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.center) to another value in the `[0.0, 1.0]` range.

```
const texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.center = new THREE.Vector2(0.5, 0.7);
texture.rotation = Math.PI;
```

Comment: You might also want to rotate your image in your image editor, save it and reload

Comment: @Hesha The image in his code is being generated dynamically through the canvas element. There is no image editor involved.

Comment: note to self : I shound stop using SO when it's past midnight